# Asciidoctor-pdf attributes don't get detected with python3 subprocess.run()

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, asciidoctor, asciidoctor-pdf

in our department we switched our documentation format to Asciidoc(tor).
For automation purposes, we want to use attributes/variables, which are read from a .yml-file.

**The problem** occurs when trying to subprocess this attributes. Using the shell, works perfectly.

`asciidoctor-pdf -a ui_host=10.10.10.10 -a ui_port=10 -a ext_host=10.11.11.11 -a ext_port=11 userman_asciidoc.adoc`

Parsing the *variables.yml* to a python3 script, format them and attach them as an unpacked list to the `subprocess.run()` call will return a valid asciidoc-pdf. However the attributes are not included.

I believe this an subprocess issue and me doing something wrong.
So, how does subprocess.run() generate the exact same output as if written to the command line?

---

The **variables.yml**:

```
ui_host: 10.10.10.10
ui_port: 10
ext_host: 10.11.11.11
ext_port: 11
```

---

The **asciidoc_build.py**:

```
import yaml
import subprocess
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="This Script builds the Asciidoc usermanual for TASTE-OS as a pdf. It can take variables as input, which yould be stored in a .yml file")
parser.add_argument("adoc_file", help="Path to the usermanual as Asciidoc (.adoc) file")
parser.add_argument("yaml_file", help="The path to the yaml file, which contains all needed variables for the TASTE-OS usermanual")

args = parser.parse_args()

with open(args.yaml_file, "r") as f:
    try:
        yaml_content = yaml.load(f)
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)

yaml_variables = []
for key, value in yaml_content.items():
    print(key, value)
    yaml_variables.append("-a " + key + "=" + str(value))

subprocess.run(["asciidoctor-pdf", *yaml_variables, args.adoc_file])
```

---

Answer (score 0):

The `-a` parameter and the actual value need to be seperated in the list that is given to the subprocess.

```
for key, value in yaml_content.items():
    print(key, value)
    yaml_variables.append("-a")
    yaml_variables.append(key + "=" + str(value))
```

Before:
`[-a ui_host=10.10.10.10, -a ui_port=10, ...]`

After:
`[-a, ui_host=10.10.10.10, -a, ui_port=10, ...]`